# Example of pairwise independent random process with expected max load $\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: probability, asymptotics, balls-in-bins

Throw $n$ balls into $n$ bins.  Each bin is selected uniformly at random but the process is only pairwise independent.  Call the maximum number of balls in any bin the **max load**.

Lemma 2 in these [notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/pscico-guyb/realworld/www/slidesS14/load-balancing.pdf) tells us that the max load is at most $\sqrt{2n}$ with probability at least $1/2$.

> Can we give an explicit uniform but only pairwise independent random process for selecting the next bin to put a ball into which gives the
>   expected max load to be $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ asymptotically?

Comment: Which process is pairwise independent, exactly?

Comment: @Did The process that selects which bin to place the next ball into.

Comment: @Did Please let me know if the question is still unclear.

Comment: [A curiously related question posted on MO at about the same time](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201912/the-power-of-two-random-choices-with-pairwise-independence).

Comment: @cardinal I did read that other question first but I don't understand why that is curious.  I can't find an explicit example what is claimed as part of that question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted (and answered) on [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31090).

Comment: @ArthurFischer I can delete it if you could enable that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

First, choose a random $k$ between 1 and $n$ to be the "crowded bin".
Next, choose a random permutation $\pi$ of $1,2,\ldots, n-1$.

Now, for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$,
$$ \mbox{put ball } i \mbox{ into bin } 
\begin{cases} k \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{with probability }\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \\
k + \pi(i) \mbox{ with probability }1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
\end{cases}$$
where the sum is taken mod $n$.

Put ball $n$ into a random bin.

Consider balls $i,j$ where $1 \leq i < j \leq n-1$. Both these balls go into the crowded bin with probability $\frac{1}{n}$, and the crowded bin is equally likely to be any of the $n$ bins. And if they don't both go into the crowded bin, by symmetry they are equally likely to be in any two different bins. Thus, the bins these two balls are placed into are independent.

Since ball $n$ is placed into a random bin, it is independent of the other balls.

The expected max load here is essentially the expected number of balls in the crowded bin, which is
$$\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n} = \sqrt{n} + o(1).$$

Comment: That is really nice and clear. Thank you.